# How to set ListView selection color until next selection?

Tags: android, listview, select, background, background-color

I have this `Selector` as `listSelector` of a `ListView`. Moreover in ListView, I have set the

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

It is taking properly blue color when the user is touching any item of `ListView`, but as soon as the user remove the finger, it turns back to black color. I want that the selected item retains blue color until and unless the user touches any other item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@color/grey" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    </selector>
```

What change I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `android:choiceMode` of the `ListView` to `singleChoice`. Furthermore you should set `android:listSelector` to the selector you already implemented and remove that selector (or any other `android:background` drawable) from the `ListView`'s items so that their background is transparent.

In addition to that you should extend your selector to react to `android:state_checked` and register an `OnItemClickListener` like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

});
```

The top level view component you use for the list items needs to implement interface `Checkable`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html for a list of classes that are already checkable out of the box. If you only want to display text `CheckedTextView` should do it for you. Otherwise, if using a custom view you have to implement this interface yourself.

Comment: I set the no background for ListView's items. In ListView, I have set the android:choiceMode="singleChoice", android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector", android:background="@android:color/transparent" and
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" . Still it is showing same effect. Here I like to mention that I have given a backgound image in the LinearLayout which holds the Listview. What is the problem?

Comment: I extended my explanation. Have a look at the second part.

Comment: I donot want to show any checkbox, just highlight the listview item. Is it not possible?

Comment: Yes, I got that. This it what I needed too and the only way to get it working was implementing a `Checkable` component as Android's default widgets have checkboxes or something similar. In case of a LinearLayout there is a good example at https://bitbucket.org/sabadow/listmultipleselect/src/84e76f295544/src/es/sabadowdev/example/selector/MyLinear.java

Answer (score 0):

in `onListItemClick`, force the view status:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        v.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: try adding an item with only android:state_selected="true"

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
    states.addState(new int[] { },
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
    imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

it may help you....

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you need to manage it from your `ArrayAdapter` class.
There you have to remember last clicked item view and position.

Basic idea is `onListItemClick` pass the clicked position and itemview to adapter there 
we will set it's background with the color you like and changed the last selected to view
background color to default color.

```
 public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private int mSelection = 0;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public void setSelection(int mSelection, View selectedItemView) {
        this.mSelection = mSelection;

        if (selectedItemView!= null && lastSelectedRow != null
                && selectedItemView!= lastSelectedRow) {
            lastSelectedRow
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_normal);
            selectedItemView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_selected);
        }

        this.lastSelectedRow = selectedItemView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Usual code logic here....

        if (mSelection == position) {
            mViewHolder.mRootView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_selected);
            lastSelectedRow = mViewHolder.mRootView; 
        } else {
            mViewHolder.mRootView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_normal);
        }


        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        View mRootView;
    }
}
```

On List Item click you need to pass clicked item and position to adapter.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listItemView,
        int position, long id) {

    if(myAdapter != null )
    {
        myAdapter.setSelection(position,listItemView);
    }
}
```

if you want to call this set selection from other point 
you can call it like this.

```
myAdapter.setSelection(position,mListViwe.getChildAt(pos));
mListViwe.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
```